# Select * Except Null Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, null, except

i'm having a problem with my database. I have the folowing:

```
create table book
(
    name_b varchaR(50) primary key,
    typee varchaR(50) not null,
    nmbr integer unique not null,
    yeare numeric(4,0) default null,
)

create table story
(
    id integer identity(1,1) primary key,
    name_s varchar(100) not null,
    chars varchar(100) not null,
    code varchaR(200) null,
    artist varchar(100) default null,
    argument varchar(100) default null,
    book_ref_name varchar(50) references book(name_b),
    book_ref_nmbr integer references book(nmbr)
)

insert into story values
('StoryName1','StoryChars1',null,default,default,'BookName1',13),
('StoryName2','StoryChars2',null,default,default,'BookName2',35),
('StoryName3','StoryChars3',null,default,default,'BookName3',125)

insert into book values
('BookName1','Type1',13,default),
('BookName2','Type2',35,default),
('BookName3','Type3',125,default)


UPDATE story
SET code = name_s + '-' + chars + '-' + book_ref_name + '-' + Convert(varchar(50), book_ref_nmbr)
WHERE code IS NULL
```

how can i make a SELECT statement that selects * from STORY except the null fields. for example if a story has no argumentist/artist i dont want that field to show up.

for example:

the results of the `select * from story where name_s = 'StoryName1'` would be the folowing [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcJAY.png) but because those two fields are NULL i would want it to be like this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5u3k.png)

for the last table to show up that way i did this `select id,name_s,chars,code,book_ref_name,book_ref_nmbr from story where name_s = 'StoryName1'`

im trying to do something like this (this code obviously doesnt exist is just an example to try to explain me better)

```
select ""notnullcollumns"" from story where name_s = 'StoryName1'
```

Comment: You could only really do this with some crazy dynamic SQL... which I don't think you would want to.  What is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: What would you expect to be returned if you selected two rows and they each had different columns with `NULL` values?  Or will you only ever select one row?!

Comment: What are you trying to do that `isnull(artist, '')` cannot?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson @SirCrispalot i dont pretend that to happen, i already thought about it and what you said would be imagining this `('StoryName1','StoryChars1',null,'John',default,'BookName1',13),
('StoryName2','StoryChars2',null,default,'Peter','BookName2',35),` right? i think i cleared that out by using the `where name_s = 'StoryName1'`. Now, imagining that i will use a `where` in every `select` i make for this purpose how can i solve this

Comment: im trying to do something like this (this code obviously doesnt exist is just an example to try to explain me better) `select ""notnullcollumns"" from story where name_s = 'StoryName1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT id, 
      'code' AS a_type, code AS a_value
  FROM story
UNION
SELECT id, 
      'artist' AS a_type, artist AS a_value
  FROM story
UNION
SELECT id, 
      'argument' AS a_type, argument AS a_value
  FROM story
UNION...
```

but if that looks good to you then you probably need to change your design.

Answer (score 3):

Remember the meaning of `*`. It's just a substitution for enumerating the projection, AKA, columns.

How would you not select a column in a given row? That makes no sense because your output must have a layout.

You should seriously think of how the output layout would be and then let us know. For now, the question does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible! You examples show two tables with just a single row each, but tables typically have more rows. What if you had a table with two rows, and only one of them had `NULL` values on those columns?

Now, what you can do is just omit the columns from your `SELECT` clause as on your example. Or maybe use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to change `NULL` values to non-`NULL`.

Comment: i understand what you're saying, if there were two or more rows in there it would'nt work, but imagine i have this `select ""notnullcollumns"" from story where name_s = 'StoryName1'` that'll actually limit the selection to 1 row, thats what i want

Comment: @Fabio, Yes, it could work like you say, but it does not exist. It's either `*` for all columns, or listing the columns manually.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go for the last select in your question? If you don't want them, then don't add them. `Select *` will return all fields (columns), regardless of the values.

PS: This smells like a multivalued field and you should avoid them:

```
chars varchar(100) not null
```

Comment: about the `chars` field, its not really chars, it means person characters present in a story